# Establish VPN Connection with Cisco RV220W w/o 3rd Party Software

Tags: macos, network, vpn, router

I'm trying to set up and establish a VPN connection between my **MacBook Air** and the **Cisco RV220W** in my office. The IPsec setup is extremely confusing and the built in client in OS X is pretty straight forward so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**Has anyone established a connection between these devices before and how did you do it?**

Can you provide a step by step procedure? I have the wits to find out my internal/external IPs etc.

Comment: I've had some battles trying to use Cisco VPN stuff with built-in VPN support on various OSes. Suffice to say, I go around Cisco VPNs now, I hate them. OpenVPN & Viscosity are my weapons of choice.

Comment: Are those apps you must use in OSX or software you must install on the remote client you're connecting to?

Comment: Part of why I have a hate-on for the Cisco VPN client for OSX is I once had a kext it installed cause kernel panics on boot after upgrading my OS X version.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: I'm trying to say I've had bad luck with the Cisco VPN client on OSX. It'll work and may be your only option. Anyway, I'm just trying to encourage you to look at OpenVPN, if it's even an option for you.